# centos+enabling mbstring extension in php.ini still not showing in phpinfo()

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I am using CentOS distro and I tried enabling mbstring in my php.ini.

My php.ini is located at `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` and I tried enabling mbstring there.

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

When I visit my phpinfo() page, the mbstring is still not enabled.

I already restarted apache too, this is my command `service httpd restart`
but still not working.

What seems to be the problem here?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using CentOs so the extensions extension is `.so`. In the above example, you are enabling windows DLL's.

Try uncomment or add `extension=php_mbstring.so`.

Comment: i tried doing that but still there's no mbstring present in phpinfo()

Comment: Make sure php-mbstring is installed `sudo yum install php-mbstring`

Comment: Yes - i tried installing php-mbstring using that command. Not sure why it isn't in my phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

1. First install mbstring

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
```

2. check if the mbstring is appearing in `php -m | grep mbstring`
3. check the extension directory in phpinfo in my case it was  `/usr/lib64/php/modules/`
4. httpd/appache is looking for extensions in `/etc/httpd/modules`
   In my case, I copied the file

```
$ cp /usr/lib64/php/modules/mbstring.so /etc/httpd/modules/mbstring.so
```

5. `sudo service httpd restart`

**Note then if you are using AWS EC2 try to stop and start the server to
reload the new modules
it works for me just after stopping and starting EC2**

6. [optional] last in php.ini put

```
[mbstring]
mbstring.language = all
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
mbstring.http_input = auto
mbstring.http_output = UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation = On
mbstring.detect_order = UTF-8
mbstring.substitute_character = none;
mbstring.func_overload = 0
mbstring.strict_encoding = Off
```